# Starting a movie clip on an upper level. Or variable issue?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm having trouble using an `ENTER_FRAME` event in a nested instance to trigger a `gotoAndPlay()` on an instance in the top level (Scene 1).

On the main timeline I have two MovieClips : `neuron1_mc` and `fiber_mc`.

On frame 2 of `fiber_mc` I have a frame label called "flex". Inside `neuron1_mc` there is an instance called `elec_mc`.

On the final frame of `elec_mc` - in the actions layer, I have the following code:

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, muscleTwitch);
function muscleTwitch(event:Event): void
{
    fiber_mc.gotoAndPlay("flex");
    removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, muscleTwitch);
}
```

I've used this a few times for different things in the past few days and it works fine, but each time I've used it, it's been playing an instance within THAT timeline. Now I'm trying to get the frame event to trigger something a few levels up - so Flash doesn't know where (or what) "flex" is because I haven't told it where `fiber_mc` is.

As you can tell I'm pretty inexperienced. I understand what I want with far better accuracy than my skill allows.

Any help with this specific case would be awesome and general advice for this type of case would be great too.

Thanks!

Comment: You are not using enterframe correctly. enterframe serves only one purpose: running the same code multiple times (at least twice). If that's not the case and your code only needs to run once then by definition enterframe should not be used. In your case here your code could be resumed to this simple line: fiber_mc.gotoAndPlay("flex");

Comment: So it would seem from code in `elec_mc` to access `fiber_mc` you would need to do the following:  `parent.parent.fiber_mc`   Or,  you could do `root.fiber_mc`.   You cannot simply access `fiber_mc` because it is not in the same scope.  Also, it's true, unless you deliberately are wanting to wait one frame, there is little point to the enter frame handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is a matter of scope (as you seem to have already guessed).

There is no item called `fiber_mc` within the `elec_mc`'s scope, so you are probably getting a #1009 error about a null object reference.

From what you've shown, it would appear you need to do one of the following to gain a reference to `fiber_mc`.

1. Crawl up the parentage until you get to the common parent of both objects fiber_mc & elec_mc.

   ```
   //the first parent is neuron1_mc, and it's parent is the main timeline, to which fiber_mc is a child
   parent.parent.fiber_mc.gotoAndPlay("flex");

   //though to avoid a compiler warning you may need to cast the parents:
   MovieClip(MovieClip(parent).parent).fiber_mc.gotoAndPlay("flex");

   //casting is just telling the compiler explicitly what kind of object something is
   ```
2. Use the `root` keyword which is a reference to the main timeline.

   ```
   MovieClip(root).fiber_mc.gotoAndPlay("flex");
   ```

Comment: ... Also, as mentioned by @BotMaster, you don't need an `ENTER_FRAME` event listener here, you can just use : `MovieClip(root).fiber_mc.gotoAndPlay('flex');` ...

Comment: @akmozo - I left a comment about that already, as it's not related to the issue at hand, I don't feel it's necessary to address it in the answer.

Comment: As the OP is, apparently, beginner, so any advice is always welcome, also for any person how need your answer and who, usually, didn't care / have time to read comments, it's better (I think) to put that in the answer.

Comment: Thanks for this help! I'v employed #2 above and it's working well. For my education though, I don't understand why the ENTER_FRAME event listener is NOT needed. As some of you may have guessed by the mc names, this is an anim showing how motor neurons interact with muscles. I have an action potential (little electric tween) moving down the axon to the synaptic terminals. At the end of that tween, I want the muscle to contract. From my limited understanding of Flash! I'm thinking the last frame of the AP tween needs to 'kick off' the "flex" tween. No? Why not? What better way to do it?

Comment: I really can't tell you how much I appreciate this help. I have done little things at work with Flash every now and then, just to impress people who only know the world of Powerpoint, but it's mostly been a display of my art skills, not coding. You guys are really awesome!

Comment: The ENTER_FRAME event is tied to the application's frame rate, and doesn't have anything to do with frames in a Movie Clips timeline.  So the event fires every frame tick of the application (so if your project is set to 24fps, the enter frame event will dispatch 24 times every second, regardless of where the playhead is in a timeline, or if a timeline is playing or stopped).

Comment: What you are/were doing, is waiting for the next `tick` before running your code.  You add the listener, which will fire on the next tick of the application, then you're removing the listener.

Comment: The code runs on whatever frame you place it on,  so calling the gotoAndPlay("flex") on the last frame of your AP tween is sufficient.